# Finite induction proof of a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Let:
$$a_1=\sqrt{a}$$
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a_n}}, \;\;\; n \in \mathbb{N}, a \geq 2$$

1.Show that $a(a-1)>0$, $a \geq 2$.

2.Show that $\sqrt{a}<a$, $a \geq 2$.

3.Suppose that $a_n<a$. Show that $a_{n+1}<\sqrt{2a}$.

4.Show that $a_{n+1}<a$

5.By the anterior steps, show that $a_n<a, \forall n \geq 1$ and $a \geq 2$.

I understood that this is a finite induction question. My thoughts are:

For item 1, I've thought to show that by induction, since we have:
$$a(a-1)=2(2-1)=2 > 0$$
for a base step, suposing that for $a$ it's valid, we have:
$$(a+1)[(a+1)-1]=a(a+1)>a(a-1)>0 \qquad (\text{because }a+1> a-1 \text{ for } a \geq 2)$$

But is that right?

For item 2, can I show it by induction too?

For item 3, it's kinda simple, because if $a_n<a$, then $\sqrt{a_n}<\sqrt{a}$, so:
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a_n}}<\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}<\sqrt{a+a}=\sqrt{2a}$$

For item 4, I know that $\sqrt{2a}<2a$, but I can't think at anything after that.

Item 5 is just a conclusion that this is an induction question.

Can anyone help me confirm item 1 and do item 2 and 4? Thanks!

Comment: For item 2, just reorder $a(a-1) > 0$ to $a^2>a$, then take the positive square root.

Comment: For item 1, it's not given that $a$ is an integer, so induction on $a$ is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For item 1, it's not given that $a$ is an integer, so induction on $a$ is not sufficient.

For item 2, just reorder $a(a-1) > 0$ to $a^2>a$, then take the positive square root.

For item 4, $2 \le a$ so $\sqrt {2a}\le \sqrt{a\cdot a}$.

Comment: I see. So do you have any idea on how can I solve item 1?

Comment: @Geaquinto $a\ge 2 > 0$, and $(a-1) \ge 2-1 > 0$, so $a(a-1)$...